# Get this alertcondition() in pinescript to be activated during certain time of day and deactivated in other time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Suppose I have this `alertcondition(go_long())` that I want to be activated only between 0930hrs and 1500hrs. For the rest of the time in the day, it should be deactivated.

How do I do that in pinescript v5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
canAlert = (hour == 9 and 30 <= minute) or (9 < hour and hour < 15)
alertcondition(canAlert and go_long())
```

Note that this calculates in exchange timezone.

Comment: I haven't tested it but it looks like the right answer. Thanks! Upvoted and marked as correct.

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with the alert system of tradingview, after having added the script to your chart don't forget to set up the alert in the alerts center too so that it can go into effect.